# How to display date and time?

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried this but it's not working. how can i dsiplay this date and time?  In the database column is define on "DATETIME". I need to display this date out of mysql.

```
$sqldate = mysql_query("select * from table where courseID = '" . $_GET['courseID'] ."' and user = '" . $_GET['userID'] . "'");
    $rsdate = mysql_fetch_array($sqldate); 

    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <?=$rsdate['datetime']?> 
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Please explain bit more clearly

Comment: try dumping the variable $rsdate and check whether "datetime" has actually come from the database

Comment: If you want only to get the date in your datetime field, in your select statement do this `SELECT date(columnName)` same also with time `SELECT time(columnName)`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. if you have date data in **$rsdate['datetime']**

```
$the_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($rsdate['datetime']));

echo $the_date;
```

you can change to the format you like

```
1) Y-m-d H:i:s
2) d/m/Y
3) ....
```

Comment: this only displaying 1970-01-01 12:00:00 but in the database date is 2013-06-27 00:00:00 in datetime column

Comment: are you sure $rsdate['datetime] = '2013-06-27 00:00:00' ?

Comment: Yes $rsdate['datetime] = '2013-06-27 00:00:00

Comment: can you double check, its working fine.

Comment: try this code. 

<?php
$rsdate['datetime'] = '2013-06-27 00:00:00';
$the_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($rsdate['datetime']));
echo $the_date;
?>

Comment: I have tried this <?php $rsdate['datetime'] = '2013-06-27 00:00:00'; $the_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($rsdate['datetime'])); echo $the_date; ?> In this I am defining date and displaying but not getting anything from database. I need that date from database

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<?php 
if(!empty($rsdate['datetime'])){
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime($rsdate['datetime']));
}
?>
```

This will echo the data in `2013-06-27` format

Comment: this only display the default date which is 1/1/1970. Does print / display the date stored in the database.

Comment: What is the date coming from database can you show that date eg `01-9-2013`

Comment: 2013-06-27 should come out of the database from datetime column

Comment: See my edited answer make sure `$rsdate['datetime'])` this is not empty

Comment: $rsdate['datetime'] is not empty 2013-06-27

Answer (score 0):

may be index datetime is not set in your db, first try to dump the value or $rsdate using `print_r` and check if the index datetime exists or not

if it exists them you can print using :

`echo date("d/m/Y",strtotime($rsdate['datetime']));`

Answer (score 0):

Convert the mySQL date value to a UNIX timestamp using

```
$timestamp = strtotime($rsdate['datetime']);
```

then you can use all options of date() to format it, for example:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

your table code should be like:

```
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <?php
echo $rsdate['datetime'];
        $timestamp = strtotime($rsdate['datetime']);
        echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
    ?> 
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Hope it will help.
:)

Comment: You can refer php manual for more formatting on the date:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Not working still date is 01/01/1970

Comment: Check the value you are getting from the data base, add a print_r($rsdate['datetime']);
on the php page and then check if it having some value in the date time format or not, it will be good if you post that value in here somewhere

Comment: see the edited answer above and try to post the output, may be something wrong with the value stored in your db.